# Error using simple IF statements, bolean variables and char matrices

Tags: java, if-statement, matrix, boolean, chars

I'm writing a program that indicates if a maze, which is a matrix of chars, has a path. My first step is to verify that the first & last rows contain a specific char. the code is very simple yet it turns to work the opposite way. This is the code:

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    final int ROWS = 5;
    final int COLUMNS = 6;
    int entryIndex = -1, exitIndex = -1, row;
    boolean work = true;
    boolean entryFound = false;
    boolean exitFound = false;
    char maze[][] = { {'a', '|', 'a', 'a', 'a', '|'},
                      {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '|'},
                      {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '|'},
                      {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '|'},
                      {'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '|'} };

        for (int col=0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            if (maze[0][col] == '|') {
                entryFound = true;
                entryIndex = col;
            }

        for (int col2=0; col2 < COLUMNS; col2++) {
            if (maze[ROWS-1][col2] == '|') {
                exitFound = true;
                exitIndex = col2;
            }

            if (entryFound == false || exitFound == false) {
                //work = false;
                System.out.println("No entry or exit for the maze had been found. Quitting");
                return;
            }
```

What I get at the end is the message that says "No entry or Exit had been found". How could this be? What could go wrong here?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  dasblinkenlight, it works out now. In this case I got the message "No entry or exit had been found" though they exist.